# PHP: File upload with Unicode

Tags: php, file-upload, unicode

When I try to loop through the `$_FILES` array in PHP I get an error, because the filenames are all in unicode. Is it somehow possible to still accept files with unicode filenames?

Example code:

```
foreach ($_FILES["files"]["error"] as $key => $error)
{

    $tmp_name = $_FILES["files"]["tmp_name"][$key];
    $name = $_FILES["files"]["name"][$key];

    logz( "$tmp_name AND $path/$name" );


    if ( $error == UPLOAD_ERR_OK )
    {
        move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, "$path/$name");

        logz( "$tmp_name -> $path/$name" );

    }
    else
    {
        logz( "upload error" );
    }

}
```

Pay attention to the log parameter; the output is:

> / -> path/%7B

The filename is not complete and `$_FILES['files']['name']` is empty.

Comment: "When I try to loop through the $_FILES array in PHP I get an error because the filenames are all in unicode." --- it sounds like "When I try to loop through the $_FILES array in PHP I get an error because it's raining"

Comment: Unicode filename by itself cannot cause the issues, so you need to provide more details.

Comment: I've added the output of the log file